# Randomly pick up variables and store it in SQL Database

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, database

I am doing online aptitude test for my company which will pick up 20 random questions from database and display it on webpage for answering.

Problem is, its not properly storing values in database (While Storing Questions and answers into database its getting jumbled up ), Please any one can help me with this issue,

Below code is getting answers from candidate ( Simple demo like pick up only 3 random questions),..

```
<form id="form1" name="quest" method="POST" action="" style="margin-left:60px;">


<?php

  $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","")
  or die(mysql_error());
  $sel=mysql_select_db("demo");

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `questions`  ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3 ");


    $rows = mysql_fetch_array($query);
    $q1 = $rows['QNo'];
    $qus1 = $rows['Question'];
    $a = $rows['Opt1'];
    $b = $rows['Opt2'];
    $c = $rows['Opt3'];
    $d = $rows['Opt4'];
    $ans = $rows['Ans'];


    echo " <b>Question:-<br></b>$qus1 <br>";
    echo " <input type=radio name = 'answer$q1' value = '$a'></input>$a &nbsp &nbsp"; 
    echo " <input type=radio name = 'answer$q1' value = '$b'></input>$b &nbsp &nbsp"; 
    echo " <input type=radio name = 'answer$q1' value = '$c'></input>$c &nbsp &nbsp "; 
    echo " <input type=radio name = 'answer$q1' value = '$d'></input>$d <br><br> ";



    $rows = mysql_fetch_array($query);
    $q2 = $rows['QNo'];
    $qus2 = $rows['Question'];
    $a = $rows['Opt1'];
    $b = $rows['Opt2'];
    $c = $rows['Opt3'];
    $d = $rows['Opt4'];
    $ans = $rows['Ans'];


    echo " <b>Question:-<br></b>$qus2 <br>";
    echo " <input type=radio name = 'answer$q2' value = '$a'></input>$a &nbsp &nbsp"; 
    echo " <input type=radio name = 'answer$q2' value = '$b'></input>$b &nbsp &nbsp"; 
    echo " <input type=radio name = 'answer$q2' value = '$c'></input>$c &nbsp &nbsp "; 
    echo " <input type=radio name = 'answer$q2' value = '$d'></input>$d <br><br> ";




    $rows = mysql_fetch_array($query);
    $q3 = $rows['QNo'];
    $qus3 = $rows['Question'];
    $a = $rows['Opt1'];
    $b = $rows['Opt2'];
    $c = $rows['Opt3'];
    $d = $rows['Opt4'];
    $ans = $rows['Ans'];


    echo " <b>Question:-<br></b>$qus3 <br>";
    echo " <input type=radio name = 'answer$q3' value = '$a'></input>$a &nbsp &nbsp"; 
    echo " <input type=radio name = 'answer$q3' value = '$b'></input>$b &nbsp &nbsp"; 
    echo " <input type=radio name = 'answer$q3' value = '$c'></input>$c &nbsp &nbsp "; 
    echo " <input type=radio name = 'answer$q3' value = '$d'></input>$d <br><br> ";

?>


<input type="submit" id="submit_id" name="SUBMIT" value="SUBMIT">
</form>
```

Next part is storing into database,..

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

if (isset($_POST['SUBMIT'])) 
{


$opt1=$_POST["answer1"];
$opt2=$_POST["answer2"];
$opt3=$_POST["answer3"];

$username=$_GET['username']; // getting this value from last webpage pls dont worry about this


  $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","")
  or die(mysql_error());
  $sel=mysql_select_db("demo");


mysql_query("insert into $username values('$qus1','$opt1')")
or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query("insert into $username values('$qus2','$opt2')")
or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query("insert into $username values('$qus3','$opt3')")
or die(mysql_error());


print "<script>window.close('techtest.php'); window.location = \"final.html\";</script>";

}

?>
```

Comment: you need to get question numbers with answers while POST parameters u get

Comment: On display of question u need to add ur question number and while posting back ur answer u need to post question number with answer/option using array Then u can get the values and insert accordingly ur questions.

Comment: i think something wrong here $opt1=$_POST["answer1"];
$opt2=$_POST["answer2"]; $opt3=$_POST["answer3"]; i am not picking the values correctly from form,...

Comment: Thats what i said, u simply getting all answer1,2,3 u should get associated Qno also, then it will be correct i think.. check wt ur sending from form and wt ur reciving..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## What's the question number? That's the question

Please try not to repeat pieces of code. So rewrite it to something like this:

```
<form id="form1" name="quest" method="POST" action="" style="margin-left:60px;">
<?php

function input_option($QNo,$Opt)
{
  echo "<input type=radio name='answer$QNo' value='$Opt'>$Opt</input>&nbsp&nbsp";
}

$count   = 3;
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
$sel     = mysql_select_db("demo");
$query   = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `questions` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT $count");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
  extract($row);
  echo "<b>Question:-<br></b>$Question <br>".
       input_option($QNo,$Opt1).
       input_option($QNo,$Opt2).
       input_option($QNo,$Opt3).
       input_option($QNo,$Opt4);
}

?>
  <input type="submit" id="submit_id" name="SUBMIT" value="SUBMIT">
</form>
```

Now I don't see anything else wrong with that page, so let's look at the other piece of code. I don't think we know what number the questions have, remember there are multiple questions in the database and you select three at random. They could have any number. So the piece of code below has to deal with that:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);

if (isset($_POST['SUBMIT'])) 
{
  $connect  = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
  $sel      = mysql_select_db("demo");
  $username = $_GET['username']; 
  foreach ($_POST as $post)
  if (substr($post,0,6) == 'answer')
  {
    $question = substr($post,6);
    $option   = ${$post};
    $sql      = "insert into $username values('$question','$option')";
    mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
  }
}

?>
<script>
  window.close('techtest.php'); 
  window.location = \"final.html\";
</script>
```

As you can see I really use the question number. Please note that security has not been a consideration when writing this example code. There's ample room for hacking this.

Comment: Hi thanx for optimizing the code, your code is displaying questions but its not storing the value in a database,..